# Count unique True/False for each variable

Tags: r, string

I have a transactional data like this

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
sample <- data.table (customerid=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7), 
                  product=c("A","A+B","A","A+B+C","A+C","B","B+C+D","C+D","A+D","A+B+D","A+B","A","A+C","B+D","D"))
```

I am trying to count how many product each customer buy totally and add it into a column name `total_product`

I tried this code in data.table

```
sample[, A:= str_detect(product,"A")]
sample[, B:= str_detect(product,"B")]
sample[, C:= str_detect(product,"C")]
sample[, C:= str_detect(product,"D")]
sample
```

the code returns

```
     customerid product A     B     C     D
1:          1       A  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2:          1     A+B  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3:          2       A  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4:          2   A+B+C  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5:          2     A+C  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6:          3       B FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
7:          4   B+C+D FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
8:          4     C+D FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
9:          5     A+D  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
10:         5   A+B+D  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
11:         6     A+B  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
12:         6       A  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
13:         6     A+C  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
14:         7     B+D FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
15:         7       D FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I saw a question on Stack that I should merge four `c(A,B,C,D)` column and count the `TRUE`
But in my case, I will have the same product count more than one time.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I read this statement  `But in my case, I will have the same product count more than one time.` as count only unique elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` on the pattern vector  (`LETTERS[1:4]`) and either specify the arguments of the function `str_detect`

```
sample[, LETTERS[1:4] := lapply(LETTERS[1:4], str_detect, string = product)]
```

Or use anonymous/lambda function

```
sample[, LETTERS[1:4] := lapply(LETTERS[1:4], function(x) 
            str_detect(product, x))]
```

---

Then create the 'total_product' count as the row wise `sum` of logical vector i.e. TRUE -> 1 and FALSE -> 0

```
sample[, total_product := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = A:D]
```

---

If we want to count the unique elements from 'product' for each 'customerid', an option is to split the column with `strsplit`, get the unique count with `uniqueN`

```
sample[, .(total_product = uniqueN(unlist(strsplit(product, 
             '+', fixed = TRUE)))), by = customerid]
```

-output

```
#     customerid total_product
#1:          1             2
#2:          2             3
#3:          3             1
#4:          4             3
#5:          5             3
#6:          6             3
#7:          7             2
```

Comment: @1darknight what is your expected output

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But maybe I was not writing it clearly enough. May I ask how could I count unique types of product (A,B,C or D) 1 customer purchase throughout all transactions?

Comment: @1darknight  Have you checked the last block of code in my post where I am using `uniqueN`

Comment: @1darknight there was commewnt which I didn't see it before it got deleted

Comment: My expected output is: 
Cus 1 purchased two product (A,B) 
Cus 2 purchased (A,B,C) 
Because sometimes they will have 2 transactions like (A+B) &(C+D) 
So counting unique products is very important to me.

Comment: @1darknight isn't the summary output showing 2, 3, etc for customer_id 1, 2

Comment: @1darknight if you can update your post with expected output column/data it would be great

Comment: I will definitely post the expected output I want in next question! Thank you! When I have enough reputation, I will come back and upvote for you!